# Kotlin MPP expect / actual with different signatures

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a manager class that has an Android and iOS impl (from a 3rd party lib). "ex. MyManagerImpl()". To construct the 3rd party manager, iOS does not require a Context but Android does. I created a common class "MyManager" which pulls out all the common methods needed to be called within commonMain.

```
//commonMain
expect class MyManager {
  fun method1()
  companion object Factory {
    makeManager(): MyManager
  }
}

val manager = MyManager.Factory.makeManager() // ex intended usage

//androidMain
MyManagerImpl(context: Context) {
  fun method1()
}

actual class MyManager private constructor(manager: MyManagerImpl) {
  ..
  actual companion object Factory {
    override fun makeManager(): MyManager {
      return MyManager(MyManagerImpl(?how to get context?))
    }
  }
}

//iosMain
MyManagerImpl() {
  fun method1()
}

actual class MyManager private constructor(manager: MyManagerImpl) {
  ..
  actual companion object Factory {
    override fun makeManager(): MyManager {
      return MyManager(MyManagerImpl())
    }
  }
}
```

What is the cleanest way to merge the two implementations? Is it possible to do so even tho they have different constructor dependencies? We would like to be able to construct the classes lazily within commonMain. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a super clean way to do this, as a general rule. There's no way to just globally grab a `Context` from Android. Although not pretty, I'd do something like this:

```kotlin
//androidMain
class MyManagerImpl(context: Context) {
    fun method1(){}
}

actual class MyManager private constructor(manager: MyManagerImpl) {

    actual companion object Factory {
        lateinit var factoryContxet :Context
        override fun makeManager(): MyManager {
            return MyManager(MyManagerImpl(factoryContxet))
        }
    }
}

class SampleApplication : Application{
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MyManager.Factory.factoryContxet = this
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to call this from any code, init the `Context` on app start. Holding that in a static reference won't show up on everybody's best practice list, but it's not a technical issue per see. Alternatively, you could do something like that with an `Activity`, but that has it's own set of issues.

Comment: thank you for your response! Since my mpp project includes an android library target I might be able to define the application class within androidMain that does this messiness and clients will just have to implement that application class. I was also thinking DI with kodein might clean things up but i was not able to figure out how I would retrieve the context within the companion object. 

I will wait to see if any other possible solutions come in and if not I'll accept your answer as it does solve my problem. 

Thanks again.

Comment: @Maurycy see my clean solution with Kodelin DI, no static references necessary: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64141659/430128.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, if you want to do a full app init with DI we do similar things with Koin. See https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPKit. The application is pushed in on app start, and the rest is injected, which is going to be kind of a similar thing here. At some point you need to deal with the fact that Android needs you to live within it's lifecycle. Since you need Application for a lot of things, I tend to override the Application class and start the dependency chain in onCreate.

Answer (score 7):

### Dependency Injection of Context

I had the same issue with the SQLDelight `SqlDriver`, which requires a context on Android, but not on iOS. With Kodein-DI or Koin, this can be done without any messy static variables by using injection for the context.

The basic concept is that expect/actual is used to create a platform-specific factory class (`ManagerFactory`).

On Android, the `actual` implementation of `ManagerFactory` takes the context as a parameter, which can be obtained from the DI context (for Kodein-DI on Android, see the `androidXModule` [code](https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/blob/7.10/framework/android/kodein-di-framework-android-core/src/main/java/org/kodein/di/android/module.kt) and [docs](https://docs.kodein.org/kodein-di/7.10/framework/android.html)).

Once the factory class has been defined in both the android and iOS DI modules, it can then be injected/retrieved in the common module, and the retrieved `MyManager` instance bound into the DI, and used wherever it is needed.

It would look something like this using Kodein-DI:

#### commonMain

```kotlin
//commonMain
expect class ManagerFactory {
    fun createManager(): MyManager
}

val sharedModule = DI.Module("common") {
    bind<MyManager>() with singleton { instance<ManagerFactory>().createManager() }

    // now you can inject MyManager wherever...
}
```

#### androidMain

```kotlin
//androidMain
actual class ManagerFactory(private val context: Context) {
    actual fun createManager(): MyManager = MyAndroidManagerImpl(context)
}

val androidModule = DI.Module("android") {
    importAll(sharedModule)

    // instance<Context> via androidXModule, see `MainApplication` below
    bind<ManagerFactory>() with singleton { ManagerFactory(instance<Context>()) }
}

class MainApplication : Application(), DIAware {
    override val di by DI.lazy {
        // androidXModule (part of Kodein's android support library) gives us access to the context, as well as a lot of other Android services
        // see https://github.com/Kodein-Framework/Kodein-DI/blob/7.1/framework/android/kodein-di-framework-android-core/src/main/java/org/kodein/di/android/module.kt
        import(androidXModule(this@MainApplication))
        importAll(androidModule)
    }
}
```

#### iosMain

```kotlin
//iosMain
actual class ManagerFactory {
    actual fun createManager(): MyManager = MyNativeManagerImpl()
}

val iosModule = DI.Module("ios") {
    importAll(sharedModule)
    bind<ManagerFactory>() with singleton { ManagerFactory() }
}
```

Comment: in this way how can you inject `MyManager` in the `commonMain` part? I guess this doesn't solve that problem or am I missing something?

Comment: @insa_c It does solve that problem. I've made some edits to the answer to hopefully make it clearer -- let me know if it makes sense now!

Answer (score 3):

Here's what we did (without dependency injection as we have not yet set it up) for our database factory to solve this problem:

We created a class called `AppContext` in a bottom level (has no other dependencies) module. In the `commonMain` we have the `expected` class:

```
expect class AppContext private constructor()
```

Then in the `androidMain` we have this:

```
actual class AppContext private actual constructor() {
    lateinit var context: Context
        private set

    constructor(context: Context) : this() {
        this.context = context
    }
}
```

The `iosMain` implementation will be the same as the `commonMain` one but with `actual` (you can do something similar to the actual Android implementation if you need to access some other properties):

```
actual class AppContext private actual constructor()
```

The key thing here is that it has the same `expected` and `actual` constructors so the compiler thinks of it as having the same signature and being the same class, but we actually have different implementations for it exposed for `Android` and `iOS`.

We create this `AppContext` on app start and pass it to the bootstrapper where we pass it to the `DbFactory` so that we can create the respective databases.

```
class DbFactory(appContext: AppContext, userId: String) : DataBaseFactory {
    private val sqlDriver =
        appContext.createSqlDriver(dbFileName = "$userId$DB_FILE_NAME_SUFFIX")
}
```

And the `expected` and `actual` implementations of `createSqlDriver`:

`commonMain`:

```
internal expect fun AppContext.createSqlDriver(dbFileName: String): SqlDriver
```

`androidMain`:

```
internal actual fun AppContext.createSqlDriver(dbFileName: String): SqlDriver =
    AndroidSqliteDriver(
        schema = KmmDb.Schema,
        context = context,
        name = dbFileName
    )
```

`iosMain`:

```
internal actual fun AppContext.createSqlDriver(dbFileName: String): SqlDriver =
    NativeSqliteDriver(
        schema = KmmDb.Schema,
        name = dbFileName
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

We're doing it like this (example for bundleId - maybe it will help you):

```
expect fun bundleId(context: Any?): String?
```

androidMain:

```
actual fun bundleId(context: Any?): String? {
    (context as? Context)?.let {
        return AndroidIdentifier(it).getBundleId()
    }
    throw Exception("")
}
```

iosMain:

```
actual fun bundleId(context: Any?): String? =
        NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleIdentifier
```

Comment: "We would like to be able to construct the classes lazily within commonMain. Is this possible?" How would you call that from common code?

Comment: thanks for the reply. This was my original "hacky" solution but due to what Kevin mentioned this unfortunately wont work for constructing objects from commonMain. I think having a static context reference is the best bet here (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another "hacky" solution, which doesn't require static references:

```kotlin
data class PlatformDependencies(
  val androidContext: Any?,
  val someIosOnlyDependency: Any?
)
```

```kotlin
// in commonMain
expect class ManagerFactory(platformDeps: PlatformDependencies) {
  fun create(): Manager
}

// in androidMain
actual class ManagerFactory actual constructor(
  private val platformDeps: PlatformDependencies
) {
  override fun create(): Manager {
    val context = platformDeps.androidContext as? Context 
      ?: error("missing context in platform deps")     
    return AndroidManager(context)
  }
}

// in iosMain: similar to androidMain, but using "someIosOnlyDependency"
```

Then you'd have to bind an instance of `PlatformDependencies` with specific values in your platform root gradle projects.

Having an object with just platform specific deps allows you to use it to construct any platform-dependent class down the DI module hierarchy.

It's still far from elegant solution, relies on discipline and somewhat leaks platforms' details into a common code, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [App Startup Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup) on Android to grab a context in your Android specific code without exposing a different API than iOS.

Basically, you add App Startup to your Android module dependencies, add a provider entry in `AndroidManifest` and implement the `Initializer` interface: Android will automatically call the `create` method with a valid context at app startup.

```kotlin
lateinit var applicationContext: Context
    private set

object MyModule

class MyInitializer: Initializer<MyModule> {
    override fun create(context: Context): MyModule {
        applicationContext = context.applicationContext
        return MyModule
    }

    override fun dependencies(): List<Class<out Initializer<*>>> {
        return listOf()
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the `applicationContext` anywhere when needed.